# Description of a person in chinese

Tags: grammar

I have three point to be clear about describing people.

1) In describing a person structures like this are usual.
我有一个好朋友叫徐浙峰，他的个子高高的，头发短短的，眼睛像葡萄一样亮.

What i understand is that in the sentences 他的个子高高的 the verb 是 is omitted after 个子 in a 是的 construction or no?  Could you say 他的个子高， without 的。 If so what is the diference?

In the second sentence 头发短短的   他 is omitted at the begining. ¿is it because it is the second sentece and we asume tha we are talking about the same person.

2) 他的个子高高的  which we saw in the first point is also seen as ，高高的鼻子 when describing as a second clause. What is the diference between 高高的鼻子  and 鼻子高高的。 Is it because the clause becaus must have a 有 when using 高高的鼻子 and a 是 maybe omitted in the first clause.

For example in the next sentece the 有 could be omitted in many of the clauses.

她有一头卷卷的黄头发，有一双乌黑的葡萄般的大眼睛，有一个高高的鼻子，还有一张樱桃小嘴。”

3) Another point for me to be clear is that i found this article in chinese. From what I understand is better not to use 有 when describing people or even may not be right.

写外貌不用“有”
作文如何写外貌？孩子的作文里总会看到类似这样的句子：“XX可漂亮了，她有一头卷卷的黄头发，有一双乌黑的葡萄般的大眼睛，有一个高高的鼻子，还有一张樱桃小嘴。”
如果你试着去掉文中的“有”，把文字重新串联一遍，会发现作文顺了很多。

例如：“XX可漂亮啦。一头卷卷的黄头发自然地披在肩上。她的眼睛太吸引人了，乌黑乌黑葡萄一般。高高的鼻子，和樱桃小嘴配合起来，有点混血的味道，同学们可喜欢她啦。”是不是读起来舒服多了？

Answer (score 1):

> What I understand is that in the sentences 他的个子高高的 the verb 是 is omitted after 个子 in a 是的 construction or no?

他的个子高高**的** compare to another similar example, say, 他的肚子肥大.

we say 他的个子高高**的** instead of 他的个子高高,

we say 他的肚子肥大 instead of 他的肚子肥大**的**.

Omitting "是" to construct 是...的 phrase, generally, for some rhetoric reasons, is done only when using twin characters. Like 他的肚子**胖胖**的，这朵花**香香**的.

If not with twin words, "是" should ***not*** be omitted. We say 他的肚子**是**肥大的 but never 他的肚子肥大的.

他的肚子肥大 is also right, but 是 and 的 are omitted together.

-

For better understanding, imagine this in English:

*I got lost in a terrible field. Trees were tall and dense, houses covered with lush mosses, like that everything around was haunted.*

"houses covered with lush mosses", grammatically should be "houses were covered with lush mosses". But the "were" it omitted. It's for a rhetoric reason, too.

> Could you say 他的个子高， without 的

Yes. 的 can be omitted that you can directly say 他个子高.

In Chinese, you can say 他个子高 他个子很高 他头发很少 他肚子胖, with 的 omitted. However, it's informal. Such is just said in casual circumstances, for simplification.

> What is the difference between 高高的鼻子 and 鼻子高高的。

There's a difference even in translation:

她有高高的鼻子: He has a high nose

她的鼻子高高的: His nose is high

Just feel the difference in English: He **has** a high nose -----vs----- His nose **is** high.

> Is it because the clause must have a 有 when using 高高的鼻子 and a 是 may be omitted in the first clause.
>
> For example in the next sentece the 有 could be omitted in many of the clauses.
>
> 她有一头卷卷的黄头发，有一双乌黑的葡萄般的大眼睛，有一个高高的鼻子，还有一张樱桃小嘴。”

Yes. It can be omitted so that the sentence is like this: 她有一头卷卷的黄头发，一双乌黑的葡萄般的大眼睛，一个高高的鼻子，还有一张樱桃小嘴 for a rhetoric reason.

Like that you say, for example.

She has a pair of twin-tails, **has** a couple of big eyes and, **has** a big long nose.

She has a pair of twin-tails, a couple of big eyes, and a big long nose.

Obviously the second one seems more beautiful.

> Another point for me to be clear is that I found this article in Chinese. From what I understand is better not to use 有 when describing people or even may not be right.

***NOT*** not right. It's right. Just seems ugly.

-

**Notice comparing with the language you've already mastered when learning a new language is important. It can tell you many things.**

Comment: 本末倒置之嫌。将形容词夹在 是……的  中 至于 泛滥的 是……的 句法本身 乃现代汉语才出现的一种有西化之嫌的产物。自然的汉语本就在主表句式中毫无接系词的必要。

Comment: I don,t understand the comment from Toosky Hierot. The level of Chinese is to high. Thanks a lot to Akuta Hinako for the answer.